# Problem when generating TOC with memoir class

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I'm trying to generate a toc using memoir class but with no success.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage{geometry}%
\geometry{margin=1in,paper=letterpaper}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{microtype}%
\usepackage{multicol}%
\usepackage{xlop}%
\usepackage{enumitem}%
\usepackage{sectsty}%
\usepackage{graphic}%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw

\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth}
\def\myhelvetfont{\def\sfdefault{mdput}}
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
    \thispagestyle{empty} 
    \sbox\feline@chapter{%
        \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
            \colorbox{nicegray}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
        }}%
    \rotatebox{90}{%
        \resizebox{%
            \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}%
        {!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
    \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
}
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap
        \makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
    }}
\makechapterstyle{daleif1}{
    \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so}
    \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\HUGE\bfseries\scshape\color{black}}
    %\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
    \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
    \renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[3.5cm]\par}
    %\renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip}
    \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\raggedleft##1\par\newpage}
    
}
\makeatother
%%chapter style
\chapterstyle{daleif1}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapitre 1}
\section{Section 1}
    \subsubsection{subsub1}
    \subsubsection{subsub2}
    \subsubsection{subsub3}
    \subsubsection{subsub4}
    \subsubsection{subsub5}
\section{Section 2}
\subsubsection{subsub1}
    \subsubsection{subsub2}
    \subsubsection{subsub3}
    \subsubsection{subsub4}
    \subsubsection{subsub5}
\chapter{Chapitre 2}
\section{Section 1}
\subsubsection{subsub1}
    \subsubsection{subsub2}
    \subsubsection{subsub3}
    \subsubsection{subsub4}
    \subsubsection{subsub5}
\section{Section 2}
\subsubsection{subsub1}
    \subsubsection{subsub2}
    \subsubsection{subsub3}
    \subsubsection{subsub4}
    \subsubsection{subsub5}

\chapter{Chapitre 3}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\chapter{Chapitre 4}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\end{document}
```

I get an empty ToC like shown bellow :
[image]

Please, I'll be grateful if you help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: didn't you see the errors in the log?

Comment: It says: ` Latexmk: Missing input file 'all.toc' (or dependence on it) from following:
  'No file all.toc.'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'all.pdf'
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'all.log' for details
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
Latexmk: Examining 'all.log'
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets`

Comment: latexmk reports errors, so check the all.log.

Comment: no file all.toc

Comment: The first error I get is `! LaTeX Error: Command \parttitlefont already defined.`, the second `! Package sectsty Error: The sectsty package doesn't work with
this document class.`. The third `! LaTeX Error: File `graphic.sty' not found.`.